# SLF4J + Logback does not log in WildFly

Tags: java, logback, wildfly

I run web application in WildFly 8 and for some reason it does not log. I use SLF4J with LOGBACK. The log file is created on deploy but it is empty. I do not see my log statements in wildfly logs either.

The class contains:

```
package com.blah.oops;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EndpointImpl.class);

log.debug("request called");
```

War contains:

- WEB-INF\lib\slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
- WEB-INF\lib\logback-classic-1.1.1.jar
- WEB-INF\lib\logback-core-1.1.1.jar
- WEB-INF\classes\logback.xml

Configuration file logback.xml contains:

```
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="10 seconds">
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_PATH}/backend-main.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <!-- PROFILER configuration -->
    <turboFilter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.turbo.MarkerFilter">
        <Marker>PROFILER</Marker>
        <OnMatch>ACCEPT</OnMatch>
        <!--  <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch> -->
    </turboFilter>

    <logger name="org.eclipse.jetty.util.log" level="info"/>
    <logger name="com.blah" level="debug"/>
    <logger name="org.apache.cxf" level="warn"/>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

console.log contains logback initialization:

```
.[0m.[0m10:19:52,716 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2) 10:19:52,489 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
.[0m.[0m10:19:52,717 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2) 10:19:52,489 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
.[0m.[0m10:19:52,717 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2) 10:19:52,490 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [vfs:/content/backend.war/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml]
.[0m.[0m10:19:52,717 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2) 10:19:52,501 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@666dc663 - URL [vfs:/content/backend.war/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml] is not of type file
.[0m.[0m10:19:52,717 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2) 10:19:52,524 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
.[0m.[0m10:19:52,717 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2) 10:19:52,529 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Setting ReconfigureOnChangeFilter scanning period to 10 seconds
.[0m.[0m10:19:52,718 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2) 10:19:52,529 |-INFO in ReconfigureOnChangeFilter{invocationCounter=0} - Will scan for changes in [[]] every 10 seconds.
.[0m.[0m10:19:52,718 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2) 10:19:52,529 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Adding ReconfigureOnChangeFilter as a turbo filter
.[0m.[0m10:19:52,718 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2) 10:19:52,532 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.PropertyAction - Could not find resource [acquirer.properties].
.[0m.[0m10:19:52,718 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2) 10:19:52,532 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
.[0m.[0m10:19:52,718 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2) 10:19:52,535 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [jettyConsole]
.[0m.[0m10:19:52,718 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2) 10:19:52,572 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender]
.[0m.[0m10:19:52,719 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2) 10:19:52,573 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [FILE]
.[0m.[0m10:19:52,719 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2) 10:19:52,575 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
.[0m.[0m10:19:52,719 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2) 10:19:52,576 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender[FILE] - File property is set to [/var/log/blah/backend-main.log]
.[0m.[0m10:19:52,719 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2) 10:19:52,591 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.eclipse.jetty.util.log] to INFO
.[0m.[0m10:19:52,719 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2) 10:19:52,592 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.blah] to DEBUG
.[0m.[0m10:19:52,719 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2) 10:19:52,592 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.apache.cxf] to WARN
.[0m.[0m10:19:52,720 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2) 10:19:52,592 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to INFO
.[0m.[0m10:19:52,720 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2) 10:19:52,713 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [FILE] to Logger[ROOT]
.[0m.[0m10:19:52,720 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2) 10:19:52,713 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
.[0m.[0m10:19:52,720 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-2) 10:19:52,714 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@30fbc21e - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
```

It seems to me that LOGBACK is successfully configured. But log messages are lost. Any idea what is going there? It makes me no sense.

Comment: I've answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26342226/3472929. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

WildFly adds slf4j as a default logging dependency Have you tried excluding the main implementation in *jboss-deployment-structure.xml* descriptor (It should go under the META-INF directory). This can be done with below lines:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
    <exclusions>
      <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
      <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
      <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
      <module name="org.jboss.logging.jul-to-slf4j-stub" />
      <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
      <module name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j" />
      <module name="org.slf4j" />
      <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
    </exclusions>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: I just found following question and exclusion of <subsystem name="logging" /> helped. Thanks nevermind. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21846329/override-logging-in-wildfly?rq=1

Comment: So am I. It is interesting that Similar questions are different when you type your question and when the question is actually submitted.

Comment: IMO: I would use the logging facilities the server already provides though. Bit strange that it is on the application's classpath by default though, in JBoss 7.x I had to put the logging module explicitly ON the application's classpath.

Comment: Works in jboss as 7.1.1.Thanks!!

Comment: When using Maven (or Eclipse / Maven), the JBoss descriptor must be placed in `src/main/webapp/META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml`. Do NOT place it under `src/main/resources/META-INF/...`.

Comment: Shouldn't `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` be placed in `WEB-INF` instead of `META-INF`... not only RedHat documentation says that but in my SpringMVC application it only worked when I put it in `WEB-INF`.

Comment: What about setting the scope to `provided` in Maven or to something similar if you are using another Build tool?

Answer (score 13):

Wildfly is using slf4j as defult logging. you have to tell jboss not to use slf4j, i am using log4j. you can do this using below jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
     <!-- exclude-subsystem prevents a subsystems deployment unit processors running on a deployment -->
     <!-- which gives basically the same effect as removing the subsystem, but it only affects single deployment -->
     <exclude-subsystems>
        <subsystem name="logging" />
    </exclude-subsystems>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your container supports child-first class loading, separation of logging can be accomplished by embedding a copy of slf4j and logback jar files in each of your applications.

For web-applications, placing slf4j and logback jar files under the WEB-INF/lib directory of the web-application is sufficient to endow each web-application with a separate logging
environment. A copy of the logback.xml configuration file placed under WEB-INF/classes will be picked up when logback is loaded into memory.

By virtue of class loader separation provided by the container, each web-application will load its own copy of LoggerContext which will pickup its own copy of logback.xml.

You can follow the solution config steps described on this post:

https://www.hhutzler.de/blog/using-logback-for-your-wildfly-project/