# logging configuration on JBoss

Tags: java, logging, jboss

I'm going to use my log4j appender in JBoss WildFly8 but I don't know how to do that. Actually, I have done researches but have not found any working solution. How could I config my App Server?

Answer (score 0):

you can reference:[Override logging in WildFly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21846329/override-logging-in-wildfly) and [Logging Configuration](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Logging+Configuration#LoggingConfiguration-Overview)
I hope this could help you ~!