# How to disable logging application logs in server.log file in Wildfly 8.2.0

Tags: java, logging, wildfly-8, jboss6.x

I am migrating my application from **JBoss 6 AS** to **Wildfly 8.2.0 AS**. I could achieve creating application logs as expected but **standalone/log/server.log** file is also getting filled with application logs.I am using **standalone-full-ha.xml** configuration. Could anyone please suggest an option to disable application logs getting filled into **server.log**.

Below section is taken from standalone-full-ha.xml:

```
<periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
<formatter>
<named-formatter name="PATTERN" /> 
</formatter>
<file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log" /> 
<suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd" /> 
<append value="true" /> 
</periodic-rotating-file-handler>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an additional custom file handler to the logging subsystem for your application category or categories:

```
  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:2.0">
    <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
        <level name="INFO"/>
        <formatter>
            <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
        </formatter>
    </console-handler>
    <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
        <formatter>
            <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
        </formatter>
        <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
        <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <append value="true"/>
    </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
    <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="MYHANDLER" autoflush="true">
        <formatter>
            <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
        </formatter>
        <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="application-audit.log"/>
        <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <append value="true"/>
    </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
    <logger category="com.mycompany.myapplication">
        <level name="INFO"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="MYHANDLER"/>
        </handlers>
    </logger>
```

See also: 
[How to log application auditing to separate file on Wildfly 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500038/how-to-log-application-auditing-to-separate-file-on-wildfly-8)

Comment: Many thanks for the response .. Sprockets. I used the options provided in the link but still I could see application logs are logged in server.log file. JFYI that I have not packed log4j in EAR deployed and instead, added the module deployment "org.apache.log4j" in <dependencies> classpath of the EAR.

Comment: I misunderstood your Q, instead you might try to add a custom handler for your logging categories. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Many thanks .. Sprockets. I will verify with the updated answer. Just adding.. application logs are generated in a separate file properly. My concern is that logs are getting logged additionally in server.log.

Answer (score 0):

This can be disabled from the admin console.
http://localhost:9990/

1. Within the console goto configurations
2. Within that choose Subsystems Logging  HandlerPeriodic.
3. Edit the configuration and set the Log Level as OFF and save.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ztSS.jpg)

PFB the image for reference.

[image]